# Extjs4: how do I add a listener when I change my panel

Tags: tabs, extjs4, listener, panel

How do I add a listener when I change my panel to another panel in same tab?

I know there is a function is tabchange, when my tab is changed and listener is working.

Like this:

```
tabchange:function(tabPanel, tab){
   if(tab.id == "selecttraffic"){
      setclickmap = 'line';
      map.addControl(clickmap);
      clickmap.activate();
   } else if(tab.id == "selectrange"){
      setclickmap = 'range';
      map.addControl(clickmap);
      clickmap.activate();
   }
}
```

But I can't find a similar function work to my panel change!!!

Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

You need to describe it more specifically. Event `tabchange` fires when a new tab has been activated/selected. What do you mean here by change my panel to another panel in same tab?